# How to make my button into an Image button?

Tags: html

I have a default button. So now how do I make it a button image? So when you click on the button the normal thing happens. What I just want is an Image on the button. Thanks.

Comment: is your button intended to submit the form, or simply fire a client-side event? if the latter, use @Sidharth Panwar answer. If the former, use @tjk answer (but it also depends on your server-side technology, if you have one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="image location" ALT="SUBMIT">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting an image instead of a button and handle its onclick event.

Comment: But the button has a submit function..How do i do that with an image ?

Comment: <input type="image" src="butup.gif" alt="Submit button">

Answer (score 1):

You can use an image as a button by specifying the **src** property:

```
<input type="image" name="submit" value="submit" src="images/button.gif" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
<button style="display:block; background: url(/path/to/image.png) no-repeat center;">
    Push me!
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript with some logic.

create one button with style attribute style="display:block"
also create required image just next to button with style="display:none"

onclick of button call javascript function.

```
function disphide()
{
    btn.style.display='none';
    img.style.display='block';
}
```

This should work